# Render element to DOM from onclick Event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, dom

I'm trying to make a very simple application that has a textArea component and a button that once clicked has a function that takes the user input and populates an object with each word and the amount of times it is repeated.

My objective is that I can then grab the entries of the object and pass it through props to another component. So far so good. My only issue is I can't seem to work out how to render this last component to the DOM iteratively, basically each word and count combo would render one `Display` component.

**TextArea component**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Display from "./Display";

interface WordandCountObject {
  [word: string]: number
};

const TextArea: React.FC = () => {
  //state to store current value on textarea
  const [textAreaValue, setTextAreaValue] = useState<string>("");
  // //state to store the count for the
  // const [count, setCount] = useState<number>(0);

  //handle change will consume what the user types in the text are element and save it to state
  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>): void => {
    setTextAreaValue(event.target.value);
  };

  //utility function that will split the string on each empty space and count 
  const splitByWordAndCount = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    //prevent page refresh//
    event.preventDefault();
    //grab textAreaValue from state and split it
    const split = textAreaValue.trim().split(" ");
    //our object to be populated with words and counts
    var obj:WordandCountObject = {};

    //iterate through split our array of strings and inject each word to the object along with the amount of times it repeats itself
    for (let i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
      //first entry for this word? add to obj and set count to 1
      if (obj[split[i]] === undefined) {
        obj[split[i]] = 1;
      } else {
        obj[split[i]]++;
      }
    }    
    debugger;
    const [[word, count]] = Object.entries(obj);

    return <Display word = {word} count = {count}></Display>;
  }



  //render it to DOM
  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <textarea value={textAreaValue} onChange={handleChange}></textarea>
        <button onClick={splitByWordAndCount}>Click Me!</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TextArea;
```

**Display Component (the second component that displays word and count combo)**

```
import React from "react";

type DisplayProps = {
  word: string;
  count: number;
};

const Display: React.FC<DisplayProps> = ({ word, count }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{word}</p>
      <p>{count}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Display;
```

Any help would be extremely appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't return anything from the splitByWordAndCount but just update the state with the resulting object and then render the Display component conditionally like so: (add this next to the button)

{resultingObjectInState.count && }